# Changing CSS for specific "id" using "this" in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My main goal is to have the user click on any "nav" class item and display a certain paragraph ID based on which nav class was clicked. I can add the .css to this post if needed but the main thing is each paragraph ID has "display" none".

Here's the "nav" items.

```html
        <div id="home" class="nav">Home</div>
  <div id="store" class="nav">Store</div>
```

Here's my paragraph items which uses an ID of the nav ID's plus the number 1 which I figured was easiest when using jQuery as you'll see below in my jQuery code.

```html
<p id="home1">Home text</p>
  <p id="store1">Store text</p>
```

This is my jQuery code which when using "alert(changeCSS)" shows the correct ID ("ID" plus the number 1).

```css
 <script type="text/javascript">

   $(".nav").click(function() {

    var changeCSS = $(this).attr('id') + "1";

    $(changeCSS).css('display', 'block');

   });
  
 </script>
```

I'm new to jQuery and programming in general so it maybe something simple I hope. Let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not adding `#` for the id selector:

```
$('#' + changeCSS)
```

Comment: Uhum, so the downvoter thinks that there is no need for a `#` for ID selectors?

Comment: Oops haha. Thank you very much, that's it! And it wasn't me who downvoted fwiw

Answer (score 0):

Also consider the built-in jQuery effects `.hide()` and `.show()`.

In your case it would be something like this:

```
            $(".nav").click(function(){

                var changeCSS = $(this).attr('id') + "1";

                $(changeCSS).show();

            });
```

This way you can easily control the speed at which your div appears or disappears:

```
$(changeCSS).hide(1000); //takes a second
```

Comment: Thanks for that! On a side note for you and anyone else, any suggestions on how to hide all paragraph text that wasn't clicked on?

Comment: you can do it by using the `.not()` selector. For instance, clicking on an element adds a temporary class, for example `'.clicked'`. Then you hide everything; then you show just your div, using something like `.not('clicked').show()`. --please click my answer as useful, if it was )

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.nav').click(function(event){
      var tag = $(event.target);
      var id= '#' + tag.attr('id') + '1';
      $(id).css('display','block')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home" class="nav">Home</div>
<div id="store" class="nav">Store</div>


<p id="home1" style="display:none">this is the home paragraph</p>
<p id="store1" style="display:none">this is the store paragraph</p>
```